# XSLT Summary with Details

Tags: xml, xslt

I was a novice in XSLT and came up with a need to create an XML from a existing XML to insert a summary of certain product.

Sample input of XML is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BATCHES>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10C00302</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1220.50</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>24.41</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10C00304</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1220.50</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>24.41</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10C00301</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1220.50</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>24.41</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10C00307</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1220.50</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>24.41</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10C00300</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1220.50</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>24.41</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10C02118</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1220.50</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>24.41</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10C02117</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1220.50</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>24.41</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10C02107</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1220.50</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>24.41</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10C02109</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1220.50</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>24.41</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10C02116</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1220.50</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>24.41</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10B00601</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000002222222</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,12,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,75,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1527.00</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>20.36</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10B00600</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000002222222</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,12,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,75,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1527.00</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>20.36</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10B01135</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000002222222</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,12,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,75,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1527.00</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>20.36</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10B05115</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000003333333</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,9,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,76,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.036</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1276.80</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>16.80</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10B05110</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000003333333</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,9,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,76,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.036</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1276.80</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>16.80</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
</BATCHES>
```

and I was wanting to get an output like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BATCHES>
  <SUMMARY>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <TOT_QTY>26.789999999999992</TOT_QTY>
    <TOT_AMT>12205</TOT_AMT>
  </SUMMARY>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10C00302</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1220.50</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>24.41</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10C00304</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1220.50</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>24.41</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10C00301</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1220.50</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>24.41</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10C00307</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1220.50</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>24.41</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10C00300</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1220.50</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>24.41</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10C02118</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1220.50</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>24.41</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10C02117</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1220.50</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>24.41</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10C02107</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1220.50</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>24.41</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10C02109</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1220.50</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>24.41</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10C02116</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000001111111</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,18,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,50,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1220.50</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>24.41</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <SUMMARY>
    <PRODUCT>000000000002222222</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,12,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,75,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <TOT_QTY>8.036999999999999</TOT_QTY>
    <TOT_AMT>4581</TOT_AMT>
  </SUMMARY>  
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10B00601</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000002222222</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,12,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,75,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1527.00</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>20.36</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10B00600</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000002222222</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,12,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,75,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1527.00</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>20.36</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10B01135</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000002222222</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,12,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,75,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.679</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1527.00</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>20.36</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>

  <SUMMARY>
    <PRODUCT>000000000003333333</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,9,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,76,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <TOT_QTY>4.072</TOT_QTY>
    <TOT_AMT>2553.6</TOT_AMT>
  </SUMMARY>  
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10B05115</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000003333333</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,9,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,76,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.036</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1276.80</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>16.80</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <PACKNO>10B05110</PACKNO>
    <PRODUCT>000000000003333333</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>BOARD,PLASTIC;P,9,U,MD,ST,2440x1220,76,D</DESCRIPTION>
    <QTY>2.036</QTY>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <AMT>1276.80</AMT>
    <UNIT_PRICE>16.80</UNIT_PRICE>
  </BATCH>
</BATCHES>
```

So far I was able to get the summary using the following XSLT but could not progress after 2 days of trying and experimenting.  I wonder someone would be so kind there to help me out.  Thanks in advance.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="BATCH" match="BATCH" use="DESCRIPTION" />    

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="BATCHES/BATCH[generate-id() = generate-id(key('BATCH', DESCRIPTION)[1])]" />
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="BATCH">

            <ITEM>
                <xsl:copy-of select="PRODUCT" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="DESCRIPTION" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="UOM" />
                <TOT_QTY><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('BATCH', DESCRIPTION)/QTY)" /></TOT_QTY>
                <TOT_AMT><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('BATCH', DESCRIPTION)/AMT)" /></TOT_AMT>
            </ITEM>

        </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="BATCH" match="BATCH" use="DESCRIPTION" />

  <xsl:template match="BATCHES">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select=
        "BATCH[generate-id()=generate-id(key('BATCH', DESCRIPTION)[1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="group" select="key('BATCH', DESCRIPTION)"/>
        <SUMMARY>
          <xsl:copy-of select="PRODUCT" />
          <xsl:copy-of select="DESCRIPTION" />
          <xsl:copy-of select="UOM" />
          <TOT_QTY><xsl:value-of select="sum($group/QTY)"/></TOT_QTY>
          <TOT_AMT><xsl:value-of select="sum($group/AMT)"/></TOT_AMT>
        </SUMMARY>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$group"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

When the main template matches `BATCHES`, then `xsl:copy`
copies the name of this (main) tag.

Looping over the groups is performed with `xsl:for-each`, but
you need the **whole** group (not just its first element),
so there is another call to `key`, saving the whole group in `group`
variable.

`<SUMMARY>` tag prints the group summary.

And the last thing to do is to print the content of the whole
group (`xsl:copy-of`).